# How to see the full conversion funnel of a customer

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads, conversions, ppc

I want to be able to query which of my converted customers came from Google AdWords, or other similar paid campaigns, so that I can figure out whether or not my campaigns are successful. Ideally I want this to get as granular as single users so that if they don't fully convert (my customers start as trial users), I can get feedback or realize that they aren't the right audience.

I know that AdWords has conversion tracking, and we use both the pixel and a google analytics event to track conversions through AdWords, but I want to get more detailed than this.

Is this even possible? Obviously Google knows the purchase path of a single customer, but because I'm not feeding them back information like an email address or username, they wouldn't be able to close the loop. Same thing with something like Mixpanel. They know the path once the user is converted and inside the app, but they don't know campaign specific information.

Is there anything out there that does this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with data segmentation in Google Analytics.

Go to `+Add New Segement` and select paid customers, then browse under the behaviour path for the funnels. You can customise segments as well based on other criteria to get more insights.

However, this would just be broad overview for segmented paid traffic. The real useful data comes from attribution modeling.

This is where you can track first iteraction/last iteraction to see if Paid traffic leads to users who return to your website and convert later, or if it's good at bringing people back who failed to convert the first time.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1662518?hl=en

An additional thing I would suggest: have your goal url as a query. For example `/contact/thank-you?id=222` instead of `contact/thank-you`.

This is great if you are keeping track ideal customers seperately in your CRM and you want to look them up to see what patterns they have i.e. returned to your website within a week after purchase.

For your goal, changing it to `starts with` has way more insights for isolated analytical observation.